# Ansible "msg": "Unable to connect to vCenter or ESXi API at IP on TCP/443: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)"

Tags: ssl, ansible, vmware, vcenter

I'm running a playbook against a host and getting this error: ` "msg": "Unable to connect to vCenter or ESXi API at 192.11.11.111 on TCP/443: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)"

We are using vcenter 6.5. I have a playbook that should let ansible controller talk to the vsphere vcenter. I exported the trusted root SSL certificates from the vsphere home page. Copied over to my ansible controller and installed with:

```
sudo mv 9dab0099.0.crt 9dab0099.r0.crl 11ec582d.0.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors
 
sudo update-ca-trust force -enable
 
sudo update-ca-trust extract
```

- able to telnet to the host on 443
- able to ping host continously
- tried changing validate_certs to: no
- tried changing validate_certs to: yes
- tried changing validate_certs to: false

My playbook:

```
- name: Add an additional cpu to virtual machine server
  hosts: '{{ target }}' 
  
  tasks: 
    - name: Login into vCenter and get cookies
      vmware_guest: 
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"   
        cluster: "{{ vcenter_cluster }}"
        datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
    - name:
      uri:
        url: https://{{ vcenter_hostname }} #/rest/com/vmware/cis/session
        force_basic_auth: yes
        validate_certs: no
        method: POST
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"   
        cluster: "{{ vcenter_cluster }}"
        datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      #register: login
  
    - name: Stop virtual machine
      vmware_guest:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: no
        folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"   
        cluster: "{{ vcenter_cluster }}"
        datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
        state: "poweredoff"

    - name: reconfigure CPU and RAM of VM
      vmware_guest:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        cluster: "{{ vcenter_cluster }}"
        datacenter: "{{ vcenter_datacenter }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
        state: "present"
        validate_certs: "false"
        folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"
        hardware:
          memory_gb: "{{ memory }}"
          num_cpus: "{{ cpu }}"
        scsi: "lsilogic"
```

ESXi fw rules are open.

Reproduced error with python 2.7.5 and python 3.6. Newest version of pyvmomi installed.

Can someone point me in the right direction from here?

Comment: It seems that certificates has some issue. Can you check https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/scenario_guides/vmware_scenarios/vmware_requirements.html#using-custom-path-for-ssl-certificates once?

Answer (score 4):

Try to put

```yaml
validate_certs: no
```

into the tasks

Comment: i ended up doing that to fix..forgot to update this post, thanks.